# When I try to enable multidex gradle indicates version conflict for support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-multidex

I tried to enable multidex in gradle file, But I faced the following error:

[image]

***I NEVER EVER have used something with version 25.2.0 !***
Why it keeps nagging about this conflict? I checked several times. And I didn't find any usage of 25.2.0 libraries in my project.

Full list of dependencies from app module:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(path: ':vaslibrary')
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

In vaslibrary I have these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'io.fotoapparat.fotoapparat:library:1.0.4'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.1'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
compile 'com.hlab.fabrevealmenu:fab-reveal-menu:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
compile 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
compile files('libs/BixolonPrinterV230.jar')
compile 'com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:2.2.3'
```

}

Comment: Some library included as dependecy use 25.2.0 support libraries

Comment: please share full code of dependencies

Comment: So what Can I do in this case? How can I find whiich library uses those libraries?

Comment: I updated the question. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @vikaskumar So do you mean by using support library 25.3.1 I could not use support:multidex library? If I tried to change All of those to 25.2.0 bu nothing changed. I still get the same error!

Comment: no it should not affect i just thought you may be using some other build version.

Comment: use this to analyse the dependencies     

./gradlew app:dependencies

Comment: try to compile `com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1` dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `gradle dependencies` command like this:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

(app being the name of your app module) to find out which dependencies rely on conflicting versions of another dependency (transitive dependencies).

In your case, the library `io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.1` has a transitive dependency on the support library with version `25.2.0` which is conflicting with support library version `25.3.1` transitively used by other dependencies.

Resolve the issue by telling the dependency that has a transitive dependency on a conflicting version to exclude that conflicting dependency with:

```
compile ('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

I left some of your dependencies out in my test run, you might need to exclude more.

Comment: I did what you said and I islo find support library 25.2.0 in com.hlab.fabrevealmenu:fab-reveal-menu. Thank you